# Coverting Hex Color String to Unsigned Long

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

```
+ (UIColor *)colorFromHex:(unsigned long)hex
{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((hex & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((hex & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(hex & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}
```

This is My Function

I set Color To View as Like THis :

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorFromHex:0x8a32cb]];
```

Now Problem is That :

I am getting color codes from the server in the plist file
as like pdColor : #8a32cb

Which I separate like this :

```
NSString *pdColor;
pdColor = [(NSString *)[temp objectForKey:@"pdColor"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@"0x"];
```

pdCOlor is in String Format.
I need to apply it here :

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorFromHex:pdColor]];
```

But it's unsigned long so its not getting right color code.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`.
The hex string can be converted to a number with `strtoul()`. Note the usage of
`+ 1` to skip over the initial `"#` character:

```
NSString *pdColor = [temp objectForKey:@"pdColor"]; // The string "#8a32cb"
unsigned long color = strtoul([pdColor UTF8String] + 1, NULL, 16);
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorFromHex:color]];
```

Comment: I liked the way of converting and removing #. so 1 up

Answer (score 0):

Please test my answer. You will get exact Result here.

```
NSScanner *scanner2 = [NSScanner scannerWithString:pdColor];
unsigned baseColor1;
[scanner2 scanHexInt:&baseColor1];
CGFloat red   = ((baseColor1 & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0f;
CGFloat green = ((baseColor1 & 0x00FF00) >>  8) / 255.0f;
CGFloat blue  =  (baseColor1 & 0x0000FF) / 255.0f;
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these methods

```
-(UIColor *) colorWithHexString: (NSString *) hexString {
    NSString *colorString = [[hexString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"#" withString: @""] uppercaseString];
    CGFloat alpha, red, blue, green;
    alpha = 1.0f;
    red   = [self colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 0 length: 2];
    green = [self colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 2 length: 2];
    blue  = [self colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 4 length: 2];
    return [UIColor colorWithRed: red green: green blue: blue alpha: alpha];
}


-(CGFloat) colorComponentFrom: (NSString *) string start: (NSUInteger) start length: (NSUInteger) length {
    NSString *substring = [string substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(start, length)];
    NSString *fullHex = length == 2 ? substring : [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@", substring, substring];
    unsigned hexComponent;
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString: fullHex] scanHexInt: &hexComponent];
    return hexComponent / 255.0;
}
```

Just pass the hex string e.g.@"#8a32cb" to first method and it will return you a `UICOLOR`

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *pdColor =[[temp objectForKey:@"pdColor"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@""];
NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:pdColor];
unsigned int hex;
[scanner scanHexInt:&hex];
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorFromHex:hex];
```